# Possible to toggle between two different colorschemes in vim

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

I have noticed that some files look better than others with different `colorscheme`s. Is there a way to toggle between two different colorschemes, for example:

```
colorscheme TextMate "OceanicNext

:nmap <leader>C colorscheme Textmate ? colorscheme OceanicNext : OceanicNext
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally Vim colorschemes set a variable `g:colors_name`

```
nnoremap <expr><silent><leader>C printf(':colorscheme %s<CR>',
    \ g:colors_name !=# 'OceanicNext' ? 'OceanicNext' : 'Textmate')
```